# What is the word for knowing you are in someone's thoughts?

Tags: logic, psycholinguistics

"Knowing you are in someone's thoughts" - is there a word for it?

The concept comes from [Epistemic logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-epistemic/) and the psychology of wellbeing depending on knowing someone's else thinking of you.

Comment: Are you looking for a positive version of 'ears burning'?

Comment: Do you mean knowing for a fact you're in their thoughts (because they've told you), or more of an intuition that you think you're in their thoughts? Bearing in mind that nobody will be thinking about you 24/7.

Comment: Knowing is knowledge acquired from communication. Intuition is belief.  @marcellothearcane I am looking for a technical term to describe why some communication modes are preferred to others.

Answer (score 2):

Loved. I think by definition if you love someone they are in your thoughts.

Comment: +1 But my archenemy is also in my thoughts...

Comment: @Jim [That's perfectly normal paranoia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cM735uHc7o0)